# WooCommerce add upsell product to the cart when product is added

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to implement a custom upsell function into my WooCommerce Theme.
When an user add a product, I need to add extra products (upsell) to its cart. That mean I have to add an extra parameter to the product which allow me to get the relation product/upsells and delete associated upsells if the product is deleted from the cart.

The user can choose these upsell products via a list of checkbox. Here is an overview of my "content-single-product.php" WooCommerce template:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php

    // Get Upsells Product ID:
    $upsells = $product->get_upsells();

    if ( sizeof( $upsells ) == 0 ) return;

    $meta_query = $woocommerce->query->get_meta_query();

    // Get Upsells:
    $args = array(
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'no_found_rows'       => 1,
        'posts_per_page'      => $posts_per_page,
        'orderby'             => $orderby,
        'post__in'            => $upsells,
        'post__not_in'        => array( $product->id )
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <ul>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
            <label for="upsell_<?php the_ID(); ?>"><input type="checkbox" name="upsells[]" id="upsell_<?php the_ID(); ?>" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" /> <?php the_title(); ?></label>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

The code above has been simplified..

Then, here is the code I added into functions.php which allow me to add upsells to the cart and add an extra row to the associated product:

```
/**
 * Add upsells as extra data for added product
 */
function add_upsells_to_cart( $cart_item_key ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( empty( $_REQUEST['upsells'] ) || ! is_array( $_REQUEST['upsells'] ) )
        return;

    // Prevent loop
    $upsells = $_REQUEST['upsells'];
    unset( $_REQUEST['upsells'] );

    // Add upsell_parent row (if not already existing) for the associated product
    if ( ! $cart_item_data['upsells'] || ! is_array( $cart_item_data['upsells'] ) )
        $cart_item_data['upsells'] = array();

    // Append each upsells to product in cart
    foreach( $upsells as $upsell_id ) {
        $upsell_id = absint( $upsell_id );

        // Add extra parameter to the product which contain the upsells
        $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['upsells'] = $upsell_id;

        // Add upsell to cart
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $upsell_id );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_upsells_to_cart' );
```

Upsells are added to the cart as expected, but the extra row seems to be dropped by something in WC.

When I do a `print_r( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ] );` at the end of the previous function, the extra upsells parameter is visible, but when I display the cart from the cart page, the upsells parameter is dropped from the cart.

Any idea?

Thanks,
E.

Comment: For anyone else, [Force Sells](http://www.woothemes.com/products/force-sells/) handles exactly this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So finally, I found the solution to my question.

The problem was happening when the cart was loaded from the session via the function `get_cart_from_session()` from `class-wc-cart.php`.

When extra key are added to a cart item, we need to inject the key via the `woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session` filter.

The user can now select an upsell, this upsell is automatically added to the cart at the same time than a a product is added. I also have a function which allow me to delete an upsell if the main product is deleted.

Here is my final code I added into my functions.php:

```
/**
 * Add upsells as extra data for added product
 */
function add_upsells_to_cart( $cart_item_key ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( empty( $_REQUEST['upsells'] ) || ! is_array( $_REQUEST['upsells'] ) )
        return;

    // Prevent loop
    $upsells = $_REQUEST['upsells'];
    unset( $_REQUEST['upsells'] );

    // Append each upsells to product in cart
    foreach( $upsells as $upsell_id ) {
        $upsell_id = absint( $upsell_id );

        // Add upsell into cart and set upsell_of as extra key with parent product item id
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $upsell_id, 1, '', '', array( 'upsell_of' => $cart_item_key ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_upsells_to_cart', 1, 6 );


/**
 * Inject upsell_of extra key cart item key when cart is loaded from session
 */
function get_cart_items_from_session( $item, $values, $key ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'upsell_of', $values ) )
        $item[ 'upsell_of' ] = $values['upsell_of'];

    return $item;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'get_cart_items_from_session', 1, 3 );


/**
 * Remove associated upsells if product removed from cart
 */
function remove_upsells_from_cart( $cart_item_key ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Get cart
    $cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

    // For each item in cart, if item is upsell of deleted product, delete it
    foreach( $cart as $upsell_key => $upsell )
        if ( $upsell['upsell_of'] == $cart_item_key )
            unset( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ $upsell_key ] );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_item_quantity_zero', 'remove_upsells_from_cart' );
```

Comment: I'm developing something similar and this q&a has been helpful, thanks! If I may suggest, when you query for your upsell list, you should consider checking visibility and availability of products. Take a look at "visibility_meta_query" and "stock_status_meta_query" ( http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Query.html#441-478 ), you can call them via $woocommerce->query and adding them to your query parameters